# Convert a recursion result to string in order to print it backwards

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, recursion

Here is my code so far:

```
import string  
def convert(num,base):
    if num==0:
        return 
    else:
        remainder = num%base
        num = num//base
        b=(str(remainder))
        print(b[::-1],end="")
        return convert(num,base)
```

Instead of printing this:

```
>>> convert(29,3)
2001
```

I need to print it backward like this (and it needs to be done by strings):

```
>>> convert(29,3)
1002
```

Seems like string does not work well with recursion:

```
>>> convert(29,3)
 ('2', ('0', ('0', ('1', None))))
```

Comment: Take a look at this maybe? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/102052/reversing-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 3):

Just change the order in which you print and recurse:

```
import string  
def convert(num,base):
    if num==0:
        return 
    remainder = num % base
    num = num // base
    convert(num, base)
    print(remainder, end="")

>>> convert(29,3)
1002
```

No idea what `convertBase()` is.

Comment: A +1 for you since the real problem was simply the order in which the recursive frames were evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Throwing in my $0.02.  I would opt for returning the entire string, instead of printing it as you go.

```
def convert(num, base):
    if num == 0:
        return ''
    num, remainder = divmod(num, base)
    return convert(num, base) + str(remainder)
```

**EDIT** might as well use the built-in divmod for computing the num and remainder.

Comment: Agree, this is the more idiomatic recursive solution. But if we are going that far, I would probably just make this iterative with a `while` loop :)

Comment: Yeah, you speak the truth.

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive function is correct in the sense that it has a exit clause (`if num == 0:`), however due to the nature of recursive functions the order of execution will be the reverse of what you wish to print out. What needs to be done here is to keep adding the remainders  to a list and then finally when you hit the exit clause, reverse that list and print it.

```
import string  
def convert(num, base, rem_list=None):
    if not rem_list:
        rem_list = []
    if num == 0:
        rem_list.reverse()
        print "".join(rem_list) 
    else:
        remainder = num % base
        num = num // base
        rem_list.append(str(remainder))
        return convert(num, base, rem_list)



>>> convert(29, 3)
1002
>>> convert(29, 3)
1002
```

Comment: And if you call this function twice what happens - you really should look at the consequences of having mutable default types.

Comment: If you call `convert(29, 3); convert(29, 3)` the second time you get `10022001`.

Comment: Why does that happen since we are calling `convert(num, base, rem_list=[])` with a default `rem_list=[]` ?

Comment: Please check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument. And your solution really doesn't reflect a recursive solution which uses the stack, but more forcing an iterative solution into recursion.

Comment: As an ugly hack I added more code. Your answer is better and I leaned something new today.

Comment: The more common approach is, `convert(x, y, rem_list=None, ...): if rem_list is None: rem_list = []`.  This could be a very good way to do it in another language that does tail-call optimization, but Python does not so there is no gain.